# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

Está gerando esse erro ao entrar na pagina.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  at
>   Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AddmenuComponent.html:8)   at
>   Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12613)
>     at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12025)   at callViewAction
>   (core.es5.js:12340)   at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12286)
>     at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12031)   at callWithDebugContext
>   (core.es5.js:13013)   at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as
>   checkAndUpdateView] (core.es5.js:12553)   at
>   ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges
>   (core.es5.js:10122)   at
>   RouterOutlet.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterOutlet.activateWith
>   (router.es5.js:5346)  at

Eu estou achando que o código no Angular que está dando esse problema, eu estou conseguindo salvar normalmente no **Postman**.

Esse é meu back-end no arquivo de rodas, fiz em Node Express

`router.post('/admin-painel/addMenu', controller.postMenu);`

Esse é minha classe de serviços no Angular;

```
adicionar(menu): Promise<Menu> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(this.url+'/admin-painel/addMenu',
        JSON.stringify(menu), { headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Essa é minha classe de componentes;

```
salvar(form: FormControl) {
    this.menuAdminService.adicionar(this.menu)
    .then(() => {
        this.notificationService.notify(`Você excluiu o menu ${this.menu.name} com sucesso`);
        form.reset();       
    })
    .catch(ErrorHandler.handlerError)
}
```

E esse é minha pagina HTML;

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <form  novalidate autocomplete="off"  >
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <mt-input-container errorMessage="Campo obrigatório e com 5 caracteres"  label="Nome">
          <input class="form-control" name="name"  
          [(ngModel)]="menu.name" required minlength="5"  
          placeholder="Digite o nome do restaurante" >
      </mt-input-container> 
    </div>  
</form>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button   class="btn btn-success pull-right" 
       ><i class="fa fa-credit-card">
      </i> Salvar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente menu esta undefined

Comment: @EduardoVargas nossa cara você tem razão, hahahaha.